# Unable to define Object in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In the below code I declared r as a variant and did `r = twb.Worksheets("Log").Range("b2")` but I am getting a Error 424 for missing object. I thought by declaring it and defining it would resolve the issue. The code breaks in the "Select Values from cells" section of the code.

The function used to handle special characters in cells is:

```
Function ValidFileName(ByVal FileName As String) As String
Dim myarray() As Variant
Dim x
'check for illegal characters
myarray = Array("[", "]", "\\", "/", "*", "\", "?", "<>", "<", ">", ":", "|", "&")
For x = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
    FileName = Replace(FileName, myarray(x), "", 1)
Next x
ValidFileName = FileName
End Function
```

And the code that I am trying to resolve is:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub RenameExcelInDir()

Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim MyExt As String
Dim MyNewName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim twb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim r As Variant '<---- Causing error
Dim getDate As Date


'Opens File Dialog Window to choose dir to search in

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .Show
       MyPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    Set twb = ThisWorkbook

    r = twb.Worksheets("Log").Range("B2")

    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "\*.*")

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        MyExt = Split(MyFile, ".")(UBound(Split(MyFile, ".")))

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)

'Loops through the worksheet collection

    For Each wks In wb.Worksheets

    Select Case wks.Name

        Case "ISU Form"
        MyNewName = ValidFileName(FileName:=wb.Sheets("ISU FORM").Range("C23").Value & "." & MyExt)

        Case "GLOBAL ISU"
        MyNewName = ValidFileName(FileName:=wb.Sheets("GLOBAL ISU").Range("M26").Value & "." & MyExt)

    End Select

    Next wks

    wb.Close

'Select Values from cells

    r.Value = MyFile
    r.Offset(, 1).Value = MyNewName
    Set r = r.Offset(1)
    Name MyPath & "\" & MyFile As MyPath & "\" & MyNewName
    MyFile = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```

Can I not use r as Variant? Does it have to be something else?

Comment: if `r` refers to a `Range`on the worksheet, you must declare it as `Range`and use `Set r = ...` to set it.

Comment: Damian, OMG what a small oversight! Thanks, that did the trick.